# Upload a PPT file and see it like a presentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The upload part is OK!

My problem is open that PPT file and show like a presentation.

I have no idea how can I do that. My server side language is PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Your client needs to have MS-Powerpoint, or at least MS Powerpoint Viewer, installed
2. Your browser needs to be capable of ActiveX
3. Ideally, you can also configure your server to send the file as MIME-type:

   "[application/vnd.ms-powerpoint](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)":